# how to calculate Ethereum inflation per each block?

Tags: uncle-blocks, block-reward

I've run Ethereum node so I can access blockchain info via rpc api provided from the node.

What I want to do is calculate Ether inflation per each block. For that, I've read many documents and I want to get confirmation whether my understanding is correct or not.

---

## There are three categories which inflate new `Ether`s per each block.

- **mining rewards** : `2 Ether` (currently)
- **uncle inclusion rewards** : 2 / 32 = `0.0625 Ether` if the block includes (an) uncle block(s)
- **uncle rewards** : `(uncle_block_number + 8 - block_number) * 2 / 8`

## For example,

#### At the block number `7280016`,

(https://etherscan.io/block/7280016), **inflated Ethers** are `2 + 0.0625 + 1.75 = 3.8125 Ether`

I didn't include transaction fees, `0.03198144598868195`, into **inflated Ethers** because they are not newly created but spent from already existing Ethers.

#### At the block number `8279967`,

(https://etherscan.io/block/8279967), **inflated Ethers** are `2 Ether` because there are no uncle(s) in this block

---

#### Is my understanding correct?

Thank you in advance~!

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you for your confirmation~!